# DocuSign iOS SDK - remove CMPopTipView from dependency

Tags: ios, docusignapi

Both My project and DocuSign project are using CMPopTipView open source code. Due that I facing following error during runtime.

```
Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-CMPopTipView.a(CMPopTipView.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CMPopTipView in:
    /Users/Mani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-cwzhebmptltodqbylbytaqjfetaa/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CMPopTipView.o
    /Users/Mani/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-cwzhebmptltodqbylbytaqjfetaa/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-CMPopTipView.a(CMPopTipView.o)
ld: 34 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there a way to remove dependency of DocuSignSDK for CMPopTipView and set it to use one present in my code base? if yes how?

Thanks,
Mani